# Are ListView and RecycleView more efficient in handling large lists than a scroll view?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, android-scrollview

Much Application is a chat program like whatsapp. So it doesn't need to display all the messages at once. Only the last messages should be shown to the user at the startup unless user scrolls and view the past ones.

I have a ScrollView that contains a large (around 1000) amount of elements(messeges). So its not much efficient performance-wise because it loads and displays all the elements at once.

In most cases its useless that it loads the entire history of msgs.

(I have think of splitting these msgs into sections and manually choosing to load them only too)

Is this functionality provided built-in with ListView or RecycleView.

I mean though we load all the elements to ListView, does it have a capability to intelligently process the elements that are shown in the screen in a particular time (or scroll level) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the main reason of using `ListView` or `RecyclerView` is that they provide you with `View` re-use. It won't load all the child-Views in one go: it will ask you to bind your data to a `View` whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Is this functionality provided built-in with ListView or RecycleView.
I mean though we load all the elements to ListView, does it have a capability to intelligently process the elements that are shown in the screen in a particular time (or scroll level) ?*

---

Yes, that's exactly what ListView does. It will be slower to scroll with it, but it will take just the necessary amount of memory.

Comment: "It will be slower to scroll with it" citation?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: where did you read that scrolling is slower with a ListView than with a ScrollView?

Comment: Well, we studied it in the university and I also have experienced it. You can even try it yourself, if you do not reuse the view, but create a new one in the `getView()` method, with just a few item (20-30) the scroll will be faster.